# show GPS-speed in SurfaceView - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gps

I want to show the GPS speed in a SurfaceView.

The GPS is in the mainActivity-Class cause I need it after the onCreate.
There is my Thread-Class, doing the loop. And GamePanel-Class that should show all the stuff.

The problem is, in GamePanel I try to show the current GPS-Speed with a textdraw but it is always 0. It looks like it does not really run the GPS method.
Why is this, can anyone help?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

float nCurrentSpeed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    this.onLocationChanged(null);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location == null){
        nCurrentSpeed = 1;
    }
    else {
        nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}
public float getCurrentSpeed() {
    return nCurrentSpeed;
}
```

}

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private MainThread thread;
private MainActivity mainActivity;

public GamePanel(Context context){
    super(context);
    //add the callback to the surfaceholder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){

}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry){
        try {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        retry = false;
    }
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();

    mainActivity = new MainActivity();
}
public void update(){
}
public void drawText(Canvas canvas){
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setTextSize(100);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));

    canvas.drawText("Speed: " + (mainActivity.getCurrentSpeed()), 10, 500, paint);
}
```

}

I am not showing the class Thread-Class, cause I guess it is not relevant.
Let me know if you need to see it.

Sorry for my bad English, I am from Germany.

I hope for your help!!!

Comment: Hello, I am still not able to solfe the problem.

Comment: Can nobody help in this issue? is it that complicated?